# How to ask recruiter to reconsider?

Tags: interviewing, recruitment, reinterviewing

I interviewed with a Forbes 10 company last month and they rejected me because the position is fairly limited in availability and it gets filled up right away. However, just yesterday I found out that the same position with same skill set and experience and same job ID has opened up again. How should I reach out to my recruiter and ask them to consider me for that vacancy?

Comment: Did the recruiter reject you or the company?

Comment: It would be of utmost help if you could just answer and not be sarcastic, thank you

Comment: Matt is right to ask this straight forward question. We do not know how far along you got in the process, or how you were rejected.

Comment: @Adam, Actually, the recruiter didn't reject you, the hiring manager/interviewing committee possibly did. That's a big difference.

Comment: Of course I know that, I am not dumb. The reason I posted this is because a month ago they had to reject me because the vacancy was filled for this particular engineering role, but a new vacancy came up yesterday. That is why I asked this question!

Comment: "How should I reach out to my recruiter and ask them to consider me for that vacancy?"  The same way you reached out to them for the vacancy that they "rejected" you from.

Comment: @adam If you react like that to such a simple and necessary clarification, I can see why you didn't get the job.

Answer (score 3):

Does that company post the job online and candidates can fill out the applications online also ?

It is normal for a candidate to reapply for a position that the candidate has been rejected for in the past.

Nowadays, most positions can be applied online via job search websites such as LinkedIn, etc... very quickly and easily.  Generally, it takes from 20 seconds to 2 minutes to fill out an application online. In most cases, it takes about 1 minute or less to apply. In some cases, the companies have the 1-click-apply option that takes about 3 or 5 seconds to apply.

Therefore, perhaps, you don't even need to ask that recruiter, and you can try to apply online if that option is available.

Answer (score 2):

Most likely, the position you saw posted yesterday went up because either they are not satisfied with any of their candidates (including you) or they paid for a run in advance. In any event, you are unlikely to benefit from asking the recruiter to reconsider. At best you can email the recruiter, thank them for everything, and suggest that they reach out to you if anything compatible comes along in the future.

Comment: So after my final rounds last month, the posting was taken down and many people in the team have told me that the team is growing rapidly, that's why I thought this would be a new vacancy

Comment: Good to know. Congrats on making the final round; that's not easy!  I think it's likely that either they moved on from you, or perhaps actually are still considering you without you knowing. I doubt they simply forgot you . By all means,  apply to the new posting if you wish.

Answer (score 0):

Whatever the reason they gave, the fact is you were apparently not suitable for the position. After only one month if they were to consider your CV again they would already have called you back.

Just let this go and move on, there's no point in insisting...